# PowerApps Unable to save data to table

Tags: sql-server, security, configuration, powerapps, onpremises-gateway

I have an on Prem gateway setup already and that seems fine.  I want to create a model driven app using SQL Server.  I have created the solution added a table from our On Prem SQL Server all ok.  I can publish the Model Driven app and play it successfully.  I then add data to the table, but when I click save, I get the following error message:

```
The specified domain does not exist or cannot be contacted
An unexpected error occurred from ISV code.
Show Details
Show Details link displays:
Error code: 0x80040224
Session Id: a91d9b79-ea81-4b51-9de9-de6f0d789cb9
Activity Id: 6696a636-3b19-4933-a170-024b0d6f3ed2
Time: Mon Oct 09 2023 09:08:13 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

Google, Youtube pasted error message into google no success.